Why is my function working only when I call it directly in the plot?
I wrote a function which rounds the value of the signal after the first maximum is obtained. However, when I call this function and store the result and plot it, I do not see the expected result.
This is the function:
def avg_aft_max(signal):

    ind = [i for i, value in enumerate(signal) if math.isclose(value, np.max(signal))][0]
    
    avg = np.mean(signal[ind:])
    
    signal_new = signal

    signal_new[ind:] = [np.max(signal) if math.isclose(avg, np.max(signal), rel_tol=1e-3) else np.max(signal) - 5e-12] * len(signal[ind:])

    return signal_new

The main script is below
      clamp_data_filtered = avg_aft_max(clamp_data.v)

        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scattergl(
                x=pins_position_slr_takeover.v,
                y=clamp_data_filtered,          # This does not work
                # y = avg_aft_max(clamp_data.v), # This works
                name=clamp_name + '_Filtered',
                mode="markers+lines",
                line=dict(width=4),
            ),
            secondary_y=False,
            row=1,
            col=1,
        )

Below are both images when I tried to plot them as I described above.
Expected output

Actual output


Your question is unclear. Add inputs and "minimal" working code. What's in signal? Change y=clamp_data_filtered to y = avg_aft_max(clamp_data.v)? We don't also know what signal_new is.

Signal has the data which is shown in the figure. Signal_new is just the signal which will be modified. I wrote it as signal new because I thought modifying signal itself is the problem

I'm just guessing here. Change signal_new = signal[:]. Note that signal is different in the third line of your code, as compared to what you passed to the function avg_max. But, it seems, that's what you wanna do. In case, that's not, move signal_new = signal[:] to the first line of your code, right after def avg_aft_max(signal):. Also, I don't see any difference between actual and expected image outputs. Is the blue thing that's missing, the difference?

Let's say Blue is the raw data, orange is the filtered data. In the actual output both are the same. Also my main issue is, everything works okay when I pass it in the plot. However it doesn't work when I store it in a variable and plot it
